# Does there exists an English word for 汉化 ？

Tags: vocabulary

汉化  means becoming more assimilated to Han culture. (like Anglicise means being more assimilated to English culture)

Historically, this has happened many times, e.g. during Khitan Empire, Jurchen Empire

Does there exists an English word for this? I am guessining not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Sinicization, just look at the [English version of 汉化 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinicization), you'll find out.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen the word 'Hanification' used in The Economist to refer to PRC policies and activities in Tibet and the far west, so that would seem relevant.

Comment: ah, they actually invented a word for this...

Answer (score 3):

The word you're looking for is "Sinicize." The literal meaning is to become "more Chinese."

But it's generally understood, in this context, that "Chinese" is really "Han." As far as I know, there is no equivalent word using "Han."

Comment: Hanisation. haha. thanks a lot. (I am sure the Chinese government would not agree with you that Chinese is really Han, seeing how much they want to ease racial tension)

Comment: @Lost1:  The Chinese government would not agree with you that Chinese is really Han," OPENLY. (But it would secretly be pleased.)

Comment: Of course, i am sure they want the ethnical minorities in the country to become ethnic minority everywhere in every province...